# Switch between dummy xserver and a real monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, x11

I would like to set up my Ubuntu 18 to use a real monitor if is available or use a dummy xserver if the monitor is not available. It is possible to setup xorg.conf to autodetect monitor and if no monitor was detected use dummy xserver?

Comment: If a monitor is not available, X server usually should start and run anyway.

Comment: Note, you can buy "dummy display" plugs (or "ghost" or "virtual display") that contain just an eprom so they can reply to EDID requests and so pretend that they are a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start your X server even in the absence of a monitor, and then activate the output with `xrandr` when the monitor becomes available (or deactivate it again).

In this way, the X server itself will also act as "dummy xserver". This might take some fiddling, and I am not sure if it will work with all hardware drivers. So the first step would be to identify your hardware driver, and read the man page for the xorg.conf for that driver.

Alternatively, have a look at something like [Xpra](https://xpra.org/) to have an X server you can always connect to, which you can optionally view on a real monitor (with a second X server). So the Xpra server would act as an "always use this dummy" server. However, OpenGL and similar acceleration etc. will be slow, or not work at all.